# Process OutputDataReceived wait for fired events to finish

Tags: c#, console, console-application, outputstream

How can I wait for an event to finish that was fired from inside OutputDataReceived? Right now it is jumping back and forth between main and the events. This is type of behaviour I want to achieve:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Create Process
    var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "somefile.exe";
    process.OutputDataReceived += OutputDataReceived;
    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();

    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("CommandToExecuteEventA");
    // Wait untill FireEventA is finished 
    // More code
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("CommandToExecuteEventB");
    // Wait untill FireEventB is finished
    // More code
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("CommandToExecuteEventC");
    // Wait untill FireEventC is finished
    // More Code
}

static void OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.StartsWith("A"))
        FireEventA(this, e);

    if (e.Data.StartsWith("B"))
        FireEventB(this, e);

    if (e.Data.StartsWith("C"))
        FireEventC(this, e);
}
```

Comment: You need to call `Process.BeginOutputReadLine`

Comment: Yea I know that... this is just demo code to explain what I mean. I'll add the line. Thanks.

Comment: OutputDataReceived runs on a worker thread.  So the "jump back-and-forth" is quite normal, you have two threads running.  Pretty unclear why waiting is necessary, your OutputDataReceived event handler cannot run again until the events are handled.  I suspect you are just confused about what happens when your program has more than one thread.

Comment: Yes you hit the nail. I am confused. Im sending commands to the Process and need to wait for the response before  continuing with execution. I need a synchronnous way to do that. Should i do that with the BaseStream?

Comment: Ok, I figured my problem was WaitForExit() it made my process hang when I tried synchronous ReadLine. My current way may not be reliable but at least it's working for the time being. I need to wrap my head around the async way.